# Unexpected elseif when running my php script

Tags: php, linux, server

I don't really know what to do. Help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

```
function handleVerChk($arrData, Client $objClient){
    $objClient->sendData('<msg t="sys"><body action="apiOK" r="0"></body></msg>');
}

function handleLogin($arrData, Client $objClient){
    $strUser = $arrData['body']['login']['nick'];
    $strPass = $arrData['body']['login']['pword'];
    Silk\Logger::Log('Client is attempting to login with username \'' . $strUser . '\'');
    $blnExist = $this->objDatabase->playerExists($strUser);
    if($blnExist === false){
        $objClient->sendError(100);
        return $this->removeClient($objClient->resSocket);{
        elseif($arrUser["Banned"] == 1)
$objClient->sendError(603);
return $this->removeClient($objClient->resSocket);
        }
    }
```

Comment: change `elseif` to `if`

Comment: Not sure if it should be an open or close brace in `->resSocket);{`, but there is a problem with braces in there somewhere (should there be an open { for the `elseif`?)

Comment: just before the `elseif` you have an opening bracket instead of a closing one. after the elseif condition you have a missing opening bracket.

Comment: There's [documentation for elseif/else if](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php). Properly indent your code or use an IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to this you have some errors

```
function handleLogin($arrData, Client $objClient){
    $strUser = $arrData['body']['login']['nick'];
    $strPass = $arrData['body']['login']['pword'];
    Silk\Logger::Log('Client is attempting to login with username \'' . $strUser . '\'');
    $blnExist = $this->objDatabase->playerExists($strUser);
    if($blnExist === false){
        $objClient->sendError(100);
        return $this->removeClient($objClient->resSocket);
    } elseif($arrUser["Banned"] == 1){
       $objClient->sendError(603);
       return $this->removeClient($objClient->resSocket);
    }
}
```